# How to do chained regex in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I was excited to learn that Perl can handle chained comparisons in version 5.32

However, I'm trying to do chained regex comparisons to keep my code shorter and cleaner

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.032;
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use feature 'say';
use autodie ':all';

if (9 > 2 < 3 < 4 > 0) {
    say 'chained expressions work.'
} else {
    say 'chained expressions do not work.'
}

my $x = 4;
my $z = 4;

if ($x == 4 == $z) {
    say 'chained equality works';
}

$x = 'x';
$z = 'x';

if ($x eq 'x' eq $z) {
    say 'chained string comparisons work.';
}

$x = '.';
$z = './.';
if ($x =~ m/\./ =~ $z) { # unfortunately this doesn't work
# equivalent of `if ( ($x =~ m/\./) && ($z =~ m/\./)) {
    say 'chained regex works.';
} else {
    say 'no chained regex.'; 
}
```

How can I correctly do chained comparisons with regex?

Comment: What would the chaining even mean here? A pattern match that then matches again? You don't capture anything. Just assume `$&`?

Comment: @tadman I've updated the question to show the equivalent of what I want

Comment: The binding operator `=~` is directional, how can you expect it to work backwards? If it could, then `'foo' =~ /bar/` would be equivalent to `'bar' =~ /foo/` and no one would know what was being matched.

Comment: @TLP I'm aware that the exact code that I wrote doesn't work, I'd just like to know how I can use regex in a chained fashion the same way that I use `==` earlier in the code.

Comment: @con In [perldoc perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity) *chaining* is described as working only with a certain set of operators. You might read that and see if it answers your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that Perl's "chaining" is more like a macro (and personally, I think "syntax" features that basically rearrange code are big red flags):

```
$x OP1 $y OP2 $z
```

This is effectively rewritten to something like this (with some other details accounted for but unimportant here):

```
$x OP1 $y and $y OP2 $z
```

This only works with certain operators—the ones that make comparisons.

Consider what this macro would do to this if it were to work:

```
$x =~ m/\./ =~ $z
```

This transformation gives you:

```
$x =~ m/\./ and m/\./ =~ $z
```

That is, the thing in the middle is on the right for the first operation and then the left for the second. `$x` would to a match operator, then the result of a match operator would bind to `$z`, which would have to be a pre-compiled pattern, I guess.

ikegami already showed that you aren't actually chaining things. You want to test things in series.

---

I was generally against this feature, but it was introduced to Perl immediately without going through an experimental cycle. In a [related Github issue I raised](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/17692), people went back and forth in the thinking about it (but note the number of reactions to [my comment that this would confuse people](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/17692#issuecomment-615878814) is quite high, but effectively ignored). In the [Perl 5 Thread](https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2020/02/msg257005.html), some people thought people would be confused, and some people that would be impossible. The second group won.

I wasn't confused or against this until after I wrote [Chain comparisons to avoid excessive typing](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2020/03/chain-comparisons-to-avoid-excessive-typing/), and the [first comment on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/fu3auk/chain_comparisons_to_avoid_excessive_typing/fmb29k0/).

But here we are.

My advice is to not use chained comparisons. Even though the docs are correct, the feature is going to confuse regular users. It doesn't act like they want it to. People tend to guess what a programming language will do based on other things they know about it. Instead of just checking every case, they intuit, sometimes incorrectly, how something will or should act.

Comment: Re "*Consider what this macro would do to this if it were to work:*", "If we use a dumb macro, it wouldn't work" is a straw man. There's no reason to use a dumb macro, and a dumb macro isn't used.

Comment: I didn't call it dumb, and I wasn't using the OP's code to make my argument. There's no straw man.

Comment: Re "*I didn't call it dumb*", You didn't *call* it, you just presumed it was: "Consider what this macro would do to this if it were to work". Note that "dumb" means "incapable of taking context-sensitive actions" when applied to processes. You presumed the macro would have to do something nonsense for binding operator, but why would the Perl devs do that? This argument is nonsense, and the very definition of a straw man argument. Noone argued the same dumb macro should be used for all operators. So tearing down that argument makes no sense and doesn't explain anything

Comment: I don't know what argument you think I'm tearing down, but this is about some feature that doesn't exist and as far as I know no one has plans for it to exist. That's why I used the subjunctive.

Comment: Re "*I don't know what argument you think I'm tearing down*", That chaining only works for certain operators because some imaginary macro wouldn't handle `$x =~ m/\./ =~ $z` correctly. Said macro wouldn't handle `-X` operators correctly either, yet those can be chained. In short everything above the dividing line. /// Re "*but this is about some feature that doesn't exist and as far as I know no one has plans for it to exist.*", And for good reasons. Just not the one you gave.

Comment: No, I'm not making that argument at all. It only works for certain operators because that's how it's implemented. It doesn't handle other operators because it doesn't. There's no casual connection there.

Comment: Maybe that's what you meant to say, but you asked us to consider what would happen if a certain macro was used. That's not talking about what's (not) implemented. Who cares what you imaginary macro does.

Answer (score 5):

While `100 <= $x < 200` has an obvious meaning, `A =~ B =~ C` does not. Which of those operands should be strings? Which of them should be match operators?  What operation should be performed?

You suggested putting a string on the RHS of the final `=~` to match against it, but that's not how `=~` works at all; the string is always on the LHS. `$s =~ /a/ =~ /b/` could possibly make sense, but it's still not obvious what that would do, especially if there are captures. As such, this isn't supported.

Here's are options if you want to chain some matches:

```perl
all { $s =~ $_ } qr/a/, qr/b/

any { $s =~ $_ } qr/a/, qr/b/

none { $s =~ $_ } qr/a/, qr/b/

notall { $s =~ $_ } qr/a/, qr/b/

all { /a/ } $s1, $s2

any { /a/ } $s1, $s2

none { /a/ } $s1, $s2

notall { /a/ } $s1, $s2
```

These functions provided by core module [List::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util).